# anova with repeated measure and blocking design or linear mixed model?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, unbalanced-classes

I'm attempting to run some statistical analysis on a field trial that was constructed over 2 sites over the same growing season.

At both sites (`Site` levels: HF|NW) the experimental design was a RCBD with 4 (n=4) blocks (`Block`, levels: 1|2|3|4 within each `Site`).
There were 4 treatments - 3 different forms of nitrogen fertiliser and a control (no nitrogen fertiliser) (`Treatment`, levels: AN, U, IU, C). 
During the field trial there were 3 distinct periods that commenced with fertiliser addition and ended with harvesting of the grass. These periods have been given the levels 1|2|3 under the factor `N_app`.

There are a range of measurements that i would like to test the following null hypothesis on:

H0 = `Treatment` had no effect on measurement

Two of the measurements I am particularly interested in are grass yield and ammonia emissions.

Starting with grass yield (`Dry_tonnes_ha`) as this is a nice balanced [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ramntwdgpn0e3/HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv?dl=0).

The data can be accessed using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

download.file('https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ramntwdgpn0e3/HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv?raw=1', destfile = "HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv", method = "auto")
raw_data <- read.csv("HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

HF_NW_grass <- raw_data %>% mutate_at(vars(Site, N_app, Block, Plot, Treatment), as.factor) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         Treatment = factor(Treatment, levels = c("AN", "U", "IU", "C")))
```

I have had a go at running an ANOVA on this using the following approach:

```
model_1 <- aov(formula = Dry_tonnes_ha ~ Treatment * N_app + Site/Block, data = HF_NW_grass, projections = TRUE)
```

I have a few concerns with this.

Firstly, how best to test assumptions?
For a simple one-way ANOVA I would use `shapiro.test()` and `bartlett.test()` on the dependent variable (`Dry_tonnes_ha`) to assess normality and heterogeneity of variance. Can I use the same approach here?

Secondly, I am concerned that `N_app` is a repeated measure as the same measurement is taken from the same plot over 3 different periods - what is the best way to build this repeated measures into the model?

Thirdly, I'm not sure of the best way to nest `Block` within `Site`. At both sites the levels of `Block` are 1:4. Do I need to have unique `Block` levels for each site?

I have another [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ax16x95m2z3fb5/HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv?dl=0) for NH3 emissions.

```
download.file('https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ax16x95m2z3fb5/HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv?raw=1', destfile = "HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv", method = "auto")
raw_data_1 <- read.csv("HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

HF_NW_NH3 <- raw_data_1 %>% mutate_at(vars(Site, N_app, Block, Plot, Treatment), as.factor) %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = factor(Treatment, levels = c("AN", "U", "IU", "C")))
```

For this I have all the concerns above with the addition that the data set is unbalanced.
At `HF` for `N_app` 1 n=3, but for `N_app` 2 & 3 n=4
At `NW` n=4 for all `N_app` levels.
At `NF` measurements were only made on the `Treatment` levels `U` and `IU`
At `NW` measuremnts were made on `Treatment` levels `AN`, `U` and `IU`

I'm not sure how to deal with this added level of complexity. I am tempted to just analyse as 2 separate site (the fact that the `N_app` periods are not the same at each site may encourage this approach).
Can I use a type iii sum of squares ANOVA here?

It has been suggested to me that a linear mixed modelling approach may be the way forward but I'm not familiar with using these.